# Can't find object in tempdb

Tags: sql-server

I'm using SQL Search by redgate to search for a key word and some of my results look like this:

```
Database |  Schema |  Object name  | Type ...
tempdb   |  dbo    |  #6FBF826D    | User table ...
```

How do I find out what this refers to? I had a look in tempdb.sys.all_objects but an object with name '#6FBF826D' isn't in there (although there are others with similar names). Am I looking in the wrong place?

For that matter, what is meant by 'user table' in this context? I didn't create any tables with names like that.

Comment: Why are looking at tempDB? It is a system database holding _temporary_ data.

Comment: User table = Not system table. I think Redgate might friendlify the names `create table #t(i int) select * from tempdb.sys.all_objects order by create_date desc` the actual object name shown is `#t__________ (lots more underscores) ____________________000000000003`

Comment: @Martin - only (AFAIK) temp tables receive such names. Most other temp objects (e.g. table variables) receive shorter hex names, such as the one shown in this post.

Comment: @Damien - That would explain it then, thanks!

Comment: @Oded - It came up in the search results, so I was trying to find out what it was. @Martin/Damien - some of the items in all_objects have 'sensible' names like EmpCustOrders, and others have hex-looking names. Would the readably-named ones be temp tables and hex-named ones be table variables, or some such?

Comment: That looks like a normal table created in `tempdb` as in `use tempdb; declare @t table(i int);create table #t(i int);create table t(i int);select * from tempdb.sys.all_objects where type='U' order by create_date desc;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the time you went looking for it, it had probably ceased to exist. It may have been a table variable (such variables receive such names in tempdb) - but if its batch had completed before you went looking for it, it would have been automatically removed.

You should never really have to worry about objects in tempdb - they're managed by SQL Server, and added and removed as required.